# Spring cloud gateway redirect request instead of forward

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I am using spring-cloud-dependencies version as 2021.0.0.

I have a created a very simple JAVA dsl route:

```
@Bean
    public RouteLocator customRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        //@formatter:off
        return builder.routes()
                .route("host_route", r -> r.host("*my-domain.com*")
                        .uri("http://my-microservice.com"))
                .build();
    }
```

Now, from my React based UI app when I call gateway for accessing API: http://my-domain.com/api/users I can see gateway returns response as 308 and from browser http://my-microservice.com/api/users gets called.

My understanding is gateway should have forwarded request to http://my-microservice.com/api/users and returned 200 instead of 308.

Please let me know if understanding is wrong. Also, how to achieve my expectation.

Here is Debug logs from Gateway:

```
o.s.c.gateway.filter.NettyRoutingFilter  : outbound route: bb5124a6, inbound: [a84a2a19-1, L:/10.240.1.132:8189 - R:/10.240.0.250:52942] 
2023-04-14 01:31:15.404 TRACE 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] o.s.c.g.filter.NettyWriteResponseFilter  : NettyWriteResponseFilter start inbound: bb5124a6, outbound: [a84a2a19-1, L:/10.240.1.132:8189 - R:/10.240.0.250:52942] 
2023-04-14 01:31:15.417 TRACE 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] o.s.c.g.filter.GatewayMetricsFilter      : spring.cloud.gateway.requests tags: [tag(httpMethod=GET),tag(httpStatusCode=308),tag(outcome=REDIRECTION),tag(routeId=host_route),tag(routeUri=http://my-microservice.com:80),tag(status=PERMANENT_REDIRECT)]
2023-04-14 01:31:15.427 TRACE 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [a84a2a19-1, L:/10.240.1.132:8189 - R:/10.240.0.250:52942] Completed 308 PERMANENT_REDIRECT, headers={masked}
2023-04-14 01:31:15.427 TRACE 1 --- [or-http-epoll-2] o.s.h.s.r.ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter      : [a84a2a19-1, L:/10.240.1.132:8189 - R:/10.240.0.250:52942] Handling completed
Logs from Apr 14, 2023 to Apr 14, 2023 UTC
```

Comment: Indeed, gateway simply returns the status from the service, so the downstream service is returning a 308 and gateway is just passing it along.

Comment: When I am calling API: http://my-microservice.com/api/users directly it returns 200 only. So, getting puzzled from where this 308 happening.

Comment: Not from the gateway, I can guarantee that. It does not change the returned status by default. Without knowing more about your application, I can't say.

Comment: @spencergibb I have updated the debug logs in summary for your reference.

Comment: That shows that the response from downstream being written to the client

Answer (score 0):

As Spencer Gibb says, this it not to do with the gateway, but with your microservice, which obviously is not aware that it "lives" behind a proxy. To resolve the issue, you should make sure that it takes the `X-Fowarded-*` headers into account when setting the host name in responses.

If your microservice is a spring application, you can use this configuration:

```
server.forward-headers-strategy: framework
```

There are three options for the value to choose from:

- `framework`: Use Spring's support for handling forwarded headers.
- `native`: Use the underlying container's native support for forwarded headers.
- `none`: Ignore `X-Forwarded-*` headers.

Be aware that this can cause a security risk if your proxy does not remove `X-Forwarded-*` headers that come from outside.